# Inside battery replacement in my laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, hp-pavilion, charger

I have a battery of laptop. Its model is MU06 (for HP pavilion dv6 laptop). It is a 6 cell (11.1 62Wh) battery. Each cell is [ICR18650](https://secondlifestorage.com/t-Samsung-ICR18650-28A-Cell-Specifications) (3.75 normal 4.30V Maximum 1400mA Standard 2800mA maximum). Can I replace each one with 3.7V 5200mA battery?
I know that more mA means more time but does my battery charger controller support 6 (cell) * 5200mA? Is it safe?

Can I use a little more/less (+- 1v) voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting mA and mAh confused. The **mA** figures are specifying the charge/discharge current in milliamps - this relates to the instantaneous power it can handle. The **mAH** is the figure you are interested in as this is the capacity based on current and time. The cell you linked to is only 2800mAh which is likely similar to the ones you already have in your battery.

However, there are no legitimate 5200mAh 18650 cells that I know of, if you see them on ebay etc. then they are likely just a scam.

At any rate, you would be unwise to try to replace the cells in your laptop's battery without having any experience. If you do something wrong you could cause a small explosion, just see the videos on YouTube of what can happen in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning mAH. You are right. In case of any replacement (with same voltage), does my charger controller handle it? I want to replace IRC18650 with better one.

Comment: Do you have a link to the cells you want to buy? Sensibly you need to buy good quality ones with built in over charge/discharge protection for safety.

Comment: I want to buy from a store. I will use original charger controller inside of battery.

Comment: You would need to check the precise dimensions of the replacement cells and compare to the existing ones so that you can be sure they fit, the different 18650's available are not all exactly the same size

Comment: Thank you. I realize that the batteries in store are fake! you save my laptop!